# "The input is not a valid Base-64 string.." error when using file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, arrays, model-binding, httppostedfilebase

I need to have a file upload on my view. To not mess with HttpPostedFileBase but rather to be able to use byte array for model binding I decided to extend ByteArrayModelBinder and implement it so that it automatically conerts HttpPostFileBase to byte[]. Here's how I did this:

```
public class CustomByteArrayModelBinder : ByteArrayModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var file = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Files[bindingContext.ModelName];
     
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    return fileBytes;
                }
     
                return null;
            }
     
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        ModelBinders.Binders.Remove(typeof(byte[]));
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(byte[]), new CustomByteArrayModelBinder());
    }
```

After doing above I was supposed to be able to have a ViewModel like this:

```
    public class Profile
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age{get; set;}
    public byte[] photo{get; set;}
}
```

In the view I create the corresponding html element like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
.........    
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.photo,new{type="file"})
<input type="submit" valaue="Save">
}
```

But when I submit the form I get the following error:

`The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.`

In fact it's not my idea, I following th guide in [this link](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/model_binding_posted_file_to_byte_array). Don't know what to do because the execution stops at this line:

```
 return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
```

Any ideas what to do?

EDIT: Controller action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Save(Profile profile){
     if(ModelIsValid){
        context.SaveProfile(profile);
     }
 }
```

But the action method is not even reached. The problem occurs prior to the action method.

Comment: can you post you controller action method?

Comment: @Overmachine, please see the edit, I've added the action method. but the error occurs prior to the action method.

Comment: I just tested the code on the linl and everything works fine, the only thing that comes up to my mind are the typos on the html you provided :/ like @Html.TextBox|For should be @TextBoxFor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes while converting base64, the + and / characters are changed to - and _. So u have to replace them as :

```
string converted = base64String.Replace('-', '+');
converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');
```

in ur **BindModel** class.